# R Shiny: Computing new Variables selected by "selectInput"

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard

I'm working on a dashbord with Shiny and want to compute new variables based on the selected Variabels by *selectInput*.
Comparable to this in normal R-Code:

```
library(dplyr) 
new_df <- old_df %>% mutate(new_1 = old_var1 + old_var2)
```

I'm able to compute new values with the *sliderInput*, but this are only single values. I want to compute a hole new variable with all the oppertunities of displaying the new variable in Tables and graphics.

Please try the followring syntax (the data is online avalible).
As you mentioned, all Inputs are working as they should.

```
 library(shiny)
 library(readr)
 library(ggplot2)
 library(stringr)
 library(dplyr)
 library(DT)
 library(tools)
 load(url("http://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/production/course_4850/datasets/movies.Rdata"))

ui <- fluidPage( 

 sidebarLayout(

# Inputs
sidebarPanel(
  h3("Plotting"),      # Third level header: Plotting

  # Select variable for y-axis 
  selectInput(inputId = "y", 
              label = "Y-axis:",
              choices = c("IMDB rating" = "imdb_rating", 
                          "IMDB number of votes" = "imdb_num_votes", 
                          "Critics Score" = "critics_score", 
                          "Audience Score" = "audience_score", 
                          "Runtime" = "runtime"), 
              selected = "audience_score"),

  # Select variable for x-axis 
  selectInput(inputId = "x", 
              label = "X-axis:",
              choices = c("IMDB rating" = "imdb_rating", 
                          "IMDB number of votes" = "imdb_num_votes", 
                          "Critics Score" = "critics_score", 
                          "Audience Score" = "audience_score", 
                          "Runtime" = "runtime"), 
              selected = "critics_score"),

  # Select variable for color
  selectInput(inputId = "z", 
              label = "Color by:",
              choices = c("Title Type" = "title_type", 
                          "Genre" = "genre", 
                          "MPAA Rating" = "mpaa_rating", 
                          "Critics Rating" = "critics_rating", 
                          "Audience Rating" = "audience_rating"),
              selected = "mpaa_rating"),

  hr(),

  # Set alpha level
  sliderInput(inputId = "alpha", 
              label = "Alpha:", 
              min = 0, max = 1, 
              value = 0.5),

  # Set point size
  sliderInput(inputId = "beta", 
              label = "Beta:", 
              min = 0, max = 5, 
              value = 2)
  ),

# Output:
mainPanel(plotOutput(outputId = "scatterplot"),
          textOutput(outputId = "description"),
          DT::dataTableOutput("moviestable"))
)  
)  
server <- function(input, output, session) {

output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
ggplot(data = movies, aes_string(x = input$x, y = input$y,
                                          color = input$z)) +
  geom_point(alpha = input$alpha, size = input$beta) +
  labs(x = toTitleCase(str_replace_all(input$x, "_", " ")),
       y = toTitleCase(str_replace_all(input$y, "_", " ")),
       color = toTitleCase(str_replace_all(input$z, "_", " ")))
 })  
vals <- reactiveValues()
observe({
vals$x <- input$alpha
vals$y <- input$beta
vals$sum <- vals$x + vals$y
  })

output$description <- renderText({
paste0("Alpha: ",input$alpha, " Beta:", input$beta," and the sum of alpha and beta:",vals$sum, ".")
})


output$moviestable <- DT::renderDataTable({
DT::datatable(data = movies, 
              options = list(pageLength = 10), 
              rownames = FALSE)
})



}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I tried different ways to solve this problem:

## 1st try:

```
vals2 <- reactiveValues()
observe({
vals2$x <- input$y
vals2$y <- input$x
vals2$sum <- vals2$x + vals2$y
})

output$description2 <- renderText({
paste0("Input y: ",input$y, " Input x:", input$x," and the sum of both variables is:",vals2$sum, ".")
})
```

Warning: Error in +: non-numeric argument to binary operator
Stack trace (innermost first):
    56: observerFunc [C:/Users/XXXXXX/Desktop/app.R#110]
     1: runApp
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer

## 2nd try:

```
output$try2 <- renderUI({
movies_2 <- movies %>% mutate(new_1 = input$y + input$x)
})

output$moviestable2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
DT::datatable(data = movies_2,
options = list(pageLength = 10),
rownames = FALSE)
})
```

Warning: Error in inherits: object 'movies_2' not found

I've no idea where I what I can try next...

## I'm very happy for every kind of help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make `movies_2` in a reactive. Your `output$try2` won't work because its expecting UI objects.

To match the call you make on the UI side I've renamed back to `moviestable` and have changed `input$x + input$y` to paste0(input$y, input$x) since they are both character.

```
movies_2 <- reactive({
  movies %>% mutate(new_1 := movies[[input$x]] + movies[[input$y]])
})

output$moviestable <- DT::renderDataTable({
  DT::datatable(data = movies_2(),
    options = list(pageLength = 10),
    rownames = FALSE)
})
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, mlegge. I got this Error: Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to binary operator.

Comment: If my response has answered your question you may click the green checkmark next to the upvote buttons.

Comment: Thanks for your new answer. Now I don't get an error again, but it's still not what I like to do. With your help I got a string variable, but I like to compute a numeric variable. Do you got an idea, how compute a numeric variable of the sum of x and y?

Comment: Ah, I understand you, please see my edits -- there should be a dplyr way to do this too

Comment: That's it! Again: Many Thanks!!